# Can SymPy Lambdify translate core functions like Add and Mul?

Tags: python, sympy, lambdify

My goal is to evaluate a basic symbolic equation such as `ad(b + c)` with my own custom implementaions of multiply and addition.

I'm trying to use `lambdify` to translate the two core SymPy functions (`Add` and `Mul`) with my own functions, but I cant get them recognised.

At this stage I'm just trying to get `Add` working. The code I have is below.

```py
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
x, y = symbols('x y')
A = [1,1]
B = [2,2]

def addVectors(inA, inB):
    print("running addVectors")
    return np.add(inA, inB)

# Test vector addition
print(addVectors(A,B))

# Now using lambdify
f = lambdify([x, y], x + y, {"add":addVectors})
print(f(A, B)) # <------- expect [3,3] and addVectors to be run a second time

# but I get the same as this
print(A + B)
```

which yields

```
running addVectors
[3 3]
[1, 1, 2, 2]
[1, 1, 2, 2]
```

I was expecting the `+` operator in the expression to be evaluated using the custom `addVectors` function. Which would mean the results looks like this.

```
running addVectors
[3 3]
running addVectors
[3 3]
[1, 1, 2, 2]
```

I tried several different configurations of the `lambdify` line and these all give the same original result.

```py
f = lambdify([x, y], x + y, {"add":addVectors})
f = lambdify([x, y], x + y, {"Add":addVectors})
f = lambdify([x, y], x + y, {"+":addVectors})
f = lambdify([x, y], Add(x,y), {"Add":addVectors})
f = lambdify([x, y], x + y)
```

To confirm I have the syntax correct I used an example closer to the documentation and replaced the symbolic `cos` function with a sin implementation.

```py
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
x = symbols('x')
    
def mysin(x):
    print('taking the sin of', x)
    return np.sin(x)

print(mysin(1))

f = lambdify(x, cos(x), {'cos': mysin})
f(1)
```

which works as expected and yields

```
taking the sin of 1
0.8414709848078965
taking the sin of 1
0.8414709848078965
```

Is it even possible to implement my own `Add` and `Mul` functions using lambdify?

I suspect my trouble is `Add` (and `Mul`) are not SymPy 'functions'. The documentation refers to them as an 'expression' and that somehow means they dont get recognised for substitution in the `lambdify` process.

Some links that I've been reading:
[SymPy cos](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#sympy.functions.elementary.trigonometric.cos)
[SymPy Add](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.add.Add)
[SymPy Lambdify](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html#module-sympy.utilities.lambdify)

Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks for reading this far.

**EDIT: Got a more general case working**

This uses a combination of the `lambdify` and `replace` functions to replace `Add` and `Mul`. This example then evaluates an expression in the form `ad(b + c)`, which was the goal.

```py
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
 
w, x, y, z = symbols('w x y z')
A = [3,3]
B = [2,2]
C = [1,1]
D = [4,4]
 
def addVectors(*args):
    result = args[0]
    for arg in args[1:]:
        result = np.add(result, arg)
    return result
 
def mulVectors(*args):
    result = args[0]
    for arg in args[1:]:
        result = np.multiply(result, arg)
    return result
 
expr = w*z*(x + y)
print(expr)
expr = expr.replace(Add, lambda *args: lerchphi(*args))
expr = expr.replace(Mul, lambda *args: Max(*args))
print(expr)
 
f = lambdify([w, x, y, z], expr, {"lerchphi":addVectors, "Max":mulVectors})
print(f(A, B, C, D))
 
print(mulVectors(A,D,addVectors(B,C)))
```

which yields

```
w*z*(x + y)
Max(w, z, lerchphi(x, y))
[36 36]
[36 36]
```

A few things to note with this solution:

1. Using the `replace` function you can replace a type with a function (type -> func). [See the docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.basic.Basic.replace).
2. The function I replace the types with have to accept multiple inputs because each type in the expression may have more than two arguments (like multiply in the example above). I only found 3 functions that accept `*args` as an input. These were `Min`, `Max` and `lerchphi`.
3. SymPy simplifies `Min` and `Max` functions since `Max(x, Min(x, y)) = x`. That meant I couldn't use `Min` and `Max` together. So I used `lerchphi` and `Max`. These functions are arbitary as I'll be translating their implementation to a custom function in the next step. However, this means I can only replace two.
4. Final step was to translate `lerchphi` and `Max` to the custom functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sympy, addition is an operation. Hence, I'm not sure if it's possible to achieve your goal by passing in custom `modules`...

However, at the heart of `lambdify` there is the printing module. Essentially, `lambdify` uses some printer to generate a string representation of the expression to be evaluated. If you look at `lambdify`'s signature, you'll see that it's possible to pass a custom printer.

Given a printer class, the addition with `+` is performed by the `_print_Add` method. One way to achieve your goal is to modify this method of the `NumPyPrinter`.

```py
from sympy.printing.lambdarepr import NumPyPrinter
import inspect

class MyNumPyPrinter(NumPyPrinter):
    def _print_Add(self, expr, **kwargs):
        str_args = [self.doprint(t) for t in expr.args]
        return "add(*[%s])" % ", ".join(str_args)

f = lambdify([x, y], x + y, printer=MyNumPyPrinter)
print(inspect.getsource(f))
# def _lambdifygenerated(x, y):
#    return add(*[x, y])

print(f(A, B))
# [3 3]
```

Note that I've no idea what implication this might creates. That's for you to find out...

Comment: Thanks @Davide_sd!. Marking this as the answer since you fixed my example to give the right output.

Comment: I wasnt able to get it to work with both add and mul together. I managed to make it work by including the replace function, which I didnt know about yesterday. I've added my version above.

Answer (score 1):

Help for your first `f` is:

```
In [26]: help(f)
Help on function _lambdifygenerated:

_lambdifygenerated(x, y)
    Created with lambdify. Signature:
    
    func(x, y)
    
    Expression:
    
    x + y
    
    Source code:
    
    def _lambdifygenerated(x, y):
        return x + y
```

In the mysin case it produces

```
def _lambdifygenerated(x):
    return cos(x)
```

The sympy `+` produces an `Add` object

```
In [20]: expr = x+y
In [21]: expr
Out[21]: 
x + y
In [22]: type(expr)
Out[22]: sympy.core.add.Add
```

but I don't know if that information can be used in `lambdify`.  I know from other SO, that `lambdify` does a rather superficial, lexical, translation of the sympy.  It does not show much sign of having a 'deep' understanding of the target module (`numpy`).

The documenation for `lambdify` is quite long.  I haven't read it all myself, yet I've answered a number of SO about it :(

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj. I wasnt aware I could use help to get the function definition of the lambdify result. Makes sense though!